# Is there a way of creating a figure that updates in real time on python's Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I am working on a project right now that requires some sort of real time updating figure. More specifically the figure would need to update and even "branch out" as the parameters of the GUI are tweaked.

For example : in the GUI I have to enter the name of restaurants, as well as my favorite meals from each of them. As I enter the restaurants name or choose from a drop down menu, the logo of the restaurant is added to the the figure, as I choose my favorite meals from it, pictures of the meals are added in order under the image of the restaurant to which they belong.

For now I am eyeing TKinter to make my GUI, but if anyone thinks that some other module would be better or offers more functionalities please educate me. It just needs to be python.

I hope my question was clear enough.

With best regards.

Comment: I guess one way to do it is to [embed matplotlib in tkinter](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_sgskip.html). Then you can use the GUI to dynamically change the figure. (IMHO this is a very difficult task, good luck)

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.  tkinter can update the display in near real time, just like every other GUI toolkit.

Comment: @BryanOakley think about something like this car  configurator by [Porsche](https://cc.porsche.com/icc/ccCall.do?rt=1611821323&screen=1920x1080&userID=CC&lang=cc&PARAM=parameter_internet_cc&ORDERTYPE=982320&CNR=C00&customID=cc&MODELYEAR=2021&hookURL=https%3a%2f%2fwww.porsche.com%2finternational%2fmodelstart%2fall%2f).
As you change an element in the configurator just one element of the car displayed changes at a time. The knowledge to do this will probably lead me to what I would need.

Comment: Have you tried anything? I don't understand what's stopping you from your goal. Create a canvas or a frame. Create a button attached to a function. In that function you can change anything you want about the canvas or frame.

Comment: I am new to TKinter, I just wanted to know if that was doable and if there is better things to use than Tkinter. Seems like you think it's perfectly doable on TKinter right ?